# Библиотека для обработки формата .lef

Tags: c++, python, library

Мне нужны библиотеки, которые обрабатывают формат ".lef" (считывают),
но я не могу их найти нигде.

Может кто может помочь?

Comment: .lef - это lenex?

Comment: любой формат файла может содержать любое содержание...

Comment: да, но я читала, что они пишутся по гостам, и вот такой, написанный по гостам он считывается

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pylef/

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ, lef - library Exchange Format File

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понимаю - этот файл должен хранить данные в XML-формате (Lenex is an XML based data exchange format for swimming) , а значит, в принципе, должен читаться любым текстовым редактором.

Проверьте для начала свой файл на корректность. Например, вот тут

https://www.swimrankings.net/resultFileTestLenex.php

Comment: Да нет, не в этом суть вопроса.
Этот файл как-то обрабатывается и по нему строится как-то модель.
так же он как-то проверяется на ошибки
но вот как это делают программы, я не поняла
ведь форматы отличаются внутренней структурой

Поэтому я ищу именно библиотеки, которые считывают, обрабатывают lef

Comment: Готовых библиотек судя по всему не существуют за ненадобностью. Программы работают с файлами, читая XML-формат.  Надеюсь, что вы понимаете, что в таком случае содержимое файла становиться "самоописаным". Стандартная библиотека языка Python уже содержит готовый XML анализатор (модуль xml ). Импортируете -  и любой Lenex файл вам становиться доступным.

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, я ошиблась, lef - library Exchange Format File

Comment: Так все  еще проще. "Library Exchange Format (LEF) is a specification for representing the physical layout of an integrated circuit in an ASCII format.". Т.е. - опять таки -  открываем ЛЮБЫМ текстовым редактором.  А вот что там написано - разбираем с помощью https://web.archive.org/web/20181031162337/http://www.ispd.cc/contests/18/lefdefref.pdf  Надеюсь, на сей раз вы ничего не перепутали.

Comment: Этот учебник я уже находила, и специальные программы, которые открывают и обрабатывают тоже. Мне же не надо просто открыть, нужно обработать их, как эти самые программы. И поэтому я начала искать библиотеки, которые их обрабатывают, хоть каким-то образом. Но попала в ступор:(
Спасибо за старания